# How to show title on <td> of table?

Tags: jquery, css, title

i have created dynamic `table` that contains dynamic data. i want to show some text as short-info [`title`] when someone move cursor to any `<td>`. any idea ???
[image]
Its sample  table containing divs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `title` property. No scripts required:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td title="foo">foo</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/filur/87XHh/